# Will closing a prepared statement delete it's result set?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

When I execute code that is like this:

```
$stmt = $connect->prepare('SELECT ...');
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($result);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
return $result;
```

Will it return whatever was in result before the statement closed or NULL? Does closing the statement delete anything that was in the bound result?

Answer (score 0):

Call [`store_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php) before closing it, so that entire resultset get's transferred o PHP's memory.